# Pandas resampling data and getting the mean

Tags: python, pandas-resample

I'm trying to resample some data in 1 minute intervals and use the mean average to represent that minute of data, but I keep getting an error:

```
DataError: No numeric types to aggregate.
```

if I try `min()` ,`max()` or `sum()` it works fine but not with mean.

for example:
`mdf = mdf.resample('1min').sum()` will work but not
`mdf = mdf.resample('1min').mean()`

I've tried converting the dtypes using but I don't understand how to do this. `mdf = pd.to_numeric(mdf)` gives the following error,

```
TypeError: arg must be a list, tuple, 1-d array, or Series
```

The dtypes for my dataframe are all objects as shown below:

```
 - NO                 object
 - NO2                object
 - O3                 object
 - ambHumidity        object
 - ambPressure        object
 - ambTempC           object
 - humidity           object
 - particulatePM1     object
 - particulatePM10    object
 - particulatePM25    object
 - tempC              object
```

This is what the dataframe looks like
[image: This is what the dataframe looks like]

Comment: It'll be easier for folks to help if you include your data in the post as text rather than an image, so that people can copy the data and play with it. This post here gives a lot of help in how to make good, reproducible code/data: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: If your data is stored as strings, then some mathematical operations may not work if they don't "know" how to implicitly convert data types. You can use pandas [to_numeric](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) to convert your object columns to numeric data that can then be "mathed"

Comment: Thanks for the advice both of you. @G.Anderson, you were right and now I managed to resolve the issue :)

Comment: @scotscotmcc I tried recreating the dataframe but the dtypes aren't the same.
my dataframe was made when I converted JSON file to a dataframe so the types didn't automatically change. I don't know how to recreate that unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first convert dtypes in all columns of the dataframe to valid data type so that mathematical functions like mean can be used.

You can convert all the columns of a DataFrame via the `apply()` method:

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

see [converting types in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891038/change-column-type-in-pandas#:%7E:text=The%20best%20way%20to%20convert%20one%20or%20more%20columns%20of,floating%20point%20numbers%20as%20appropriate.)

Comment: that didn't work, type error.
TypeError: arg must be a list, tuple, 1-d array, or Series

I tried pd.to_numeric(df) before and I got the same error.

Comment: You're right, I forgot it only operates on a series at a time. Cheerfully withdrawn!